# How to run a single query to achieve the following result?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table -

```
ID  Start Duration
1   343     342
1   434     32
1   562     12
```

I want to run a query in sql-lite to get the first start, last start and last Duration and number of such ID's.

I tried following to achieve this.

```
SELECT MIN(Start),COUNT(ID) FROM event_list where ID=1 ORDER BY Start;
```

With this, I am able to get the First Start and the number of ID's. But, I want to get the Last Start + Last Duration. i.e. 562 + 12. However, I don't have the LAST function supported in the sql-lite. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Since there is no LAST may be MAX could help.

Comment: Not able to form the query actually.

Comment: I am looking for duration where start=max(start) and ID=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT duration 
FROM event_list 
WHERE start = (SELECT Max(Start)  
               FROM event_list 
               WHERE ID=1);
```

or

```
SELECT duration , 
       Max(Start)  
FROM event_list 
WHERE ID=1;
```

Comment: I want to pick up 12 as duration here. When I will do SELECT duration , Max(Start)  FROM event_list WHERE ID=1; How can you guarantee that the duration is for the MAX(Start)

Comment: Because it is. Check in your table, execute the query and you'll see. But if unsure, execute the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried (select Duration from event_list order by Duration DESC limit 1) as Sub Query for the LAST function ?